# ERROR: does not name a type

Tags: c++, types, include

I'm implementing a chess game in c++ and some of the classes are "Board" and "Piece".
There are classes "Rook", "King",... etc inherited from "Piece".

So a board is a 2D array of pieces and so board.h has piece.h included.

For recent development (on implementing moves) I wanted to give the pieces access to the board. 
so in piece.h I included board.h.

This now creates above error.

Some code:

```
//Function in piece.h
#include "board.h"
bool Piece::move( int toX, int toY, bool enemyPawn, const Board & b )
```

```
Error: Board does not name a type
Error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘b’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: How do you define Board?

Comment: The problem is likely in board.h, because the Piece::move definition looks fine.

Comment: These are the includes of board.h

`#include "bishop.h"`
`#include "king.h"`
`#include "knight.h"`
`#include "pawn.h"`
`#include "queen.h"`
`#include "rook.h"`

So I never include Piece directly

Comment: board includes bishop, bishop includes piece, piece includes board?

Comment: Does your board contain empty pieces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since move only uses a reference, you could definitely avoid the inclusion of board.h and only forward declare your class Board. If you really need to have piece know about board and board know about piece, you could declare an interface class to Board (pure abstract) and include that interface instead of the board making sure to make board derive from the interface – Martin just now edit

Answer (score 1):

In `board.h`: put `class Board;` (with semicolon!) before `include piece.h`.
In `piece.h`: put `class Piece;` (with semicolon!) before `include board.h`.
In general, if I define a class in a header, I put `class <classname>;` at the top of the file, *above any includes*.

You have what's called a circular dependency.  Both headers try to include each other, and either fail (if you have include guards) or infinite loop (without guards). Either way, this "forward declaration" should solve the problem.

If the classes are so tied together that this doesn't fix them, you'll have to "untie" them.  Move the function definitions for piece/bishop/king/etc to their respective `.cpp` files (if they weren't already), make sure that the headers only use `board&` and `board*` (but not `board` by value), and then replace `#include "board";` with `class board;`.  This tells the compiler that a "unknown" board type exists, and it can pass it by pointer and reference.  Then `piece.h` will have *no* dependencies, and can be included from any file correctly, like `board.h`.

Comment: I do use include guards, and it only throws more errors (although the solution is logical)  
  
invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Piece’  
forward declaration of ‘struct Piece’

Comment: Did the forward declaration (`class Board;`) above the includes not work?

Comment: I get a bunch of more errors. (Incomplete struct Piece used in nested name specifier, Color has not been declared)

Comment: @TheDudeAbides: Your classes are too tied together.  I added description for how to untie.

Comment: This is really useful in Qt. I have to open a window A from B and viceversa, and without this "trick" I didn't know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a circular dependency. One hint I read recently is to imagine how you would define both classes in a single header file, such that each knew about the other; the answer is, you can't.

To break the circular dependency you need to use a forward declaration for one of the classes, rather than including its header file. Rather than `#include "board.h"`, just do `class Board;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pimpl pattern: See http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm